# Accessing object properties in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to access properties of a custom object in PHP:

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AED extends Model {

    protected $table = 'aeds';
    protected $fillable = ['owner', 'street', 'postal_code', 'locality', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'annotation_type'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public $id;
    public $owner;
    public $object;
    public $street;
    public $postalCode;
    public $locality;
    public $latitude;
    public $longitude;
    public $annotation_type;
    public $distance;

    public function set($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if(property_exists($this, $key)) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code to access these properties:

```
<?php
namespace App\Transformer;

use App\Classes\AED;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;


class AEDTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {
    public function transform(AED $aed) {
        return [
            'data' => $aed->owner
        ];
    }
}
```

When I call the function, I get this as a response:

```
{
data: [
{
data: null
}
],
meta: "TestMeta"
}
```

The strange thing is, when I just var_dump the object I get the full info:

```
...
 protected 'original' => 
    array (size=11)
      'id' => int 1
      'owner' => string 'Owner 1' (length=7)
      'object' => string 'Object 1' (length=8)
      'street' => string 'Street 1' (length=8)
      'postal_code' => string '11111' (length=5)
      'locality' => string 'Locality 1' (length=10)
      'latitude' => float 100
      'longitude' => float 100
      'annotation_type' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
...
```

So the data can be taken from the database as expected and is being received as well. Why does the accessing not work then and I receive a "null".

I use the "set" method inside the custom function here:

```
class AEDHelper {
    static public function searchAED($position) {
        $var1 = $position['latitude'];
        $var2 = $position['longitude'];
        $var3 = $position['latitude'];

        $queryResults = DB::select(DB::raw("SQLCODE"));
        $results = [];

        foreach ($queryResults as $results) {
            $aed = new AED();
            $aed->set($results);
            $results[] = $aed;
        }

        return $results;

    }
```

Here I create a new AED() instance. So I would guess I need to define the object properties therefore as now not Eloquent will be used but a custom AED class needs to be instantiated for displaying SQL results.

Best

Comment: you don't have to define fields in your model. Eloquent makes them available dynamically.

Comment: I removed the fields and now it works. but what if I would need fields later on to access them? How do I properly fill them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to define fields in your model. Eloquent makes them available dynamically.

if you want to fill those fields you can without having them in your model. because the field will be available if you try to set a value for it.

here is how

```
$aed = new AED;
$aed->owner =  "The Owner";
$aed->object = "The Object";
....
....
....

$aed->save();
```

or this will work as well

```
AED::create([
  'owner' => "The Owner",
  'object' => "The Object",
  .....
  .....
  .....
]);
```

or if you want update an existing model.

```
$aed = AED::find(1);
// change owner
$aed->owner= "New Owner";

$aed->save();
```

Comment: But why is my object then not filled with data in the example above where I inserted the properties in my custom class and the output is "null", whereas when I call the object itself and return it, I see the values existing. So I guess the object properties are not set?

Comment: where you are calling the ``AED::set()`` method

Comment: Just updated my question. I use this method to create instances of AED when I receive custom DB query results and want to set each of them using the AED class. So I guess I need the definition of the properties then?

Comment: But as soon as I define this property, I lose the information received by the eloquent query

Comment: Php assign without declare